# How to remove the tmp- from my download name

Tags: php

So when a user downloads a file I currently have it pull the song name through something that looks like this.

```
$songs = file_get_contents('https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/'.$id.'/stream?client_id='.$myID.'');
$filename = './tmp/' . stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($songTitle)) . '.mp3';
$filenames = '/tmp/' . stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($songTitle)) . '.mp3';
$trying = '' . stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($songTitle)) . '';
$songname = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($songTitle));
file_put_contents($filename, $songs);


<form method="POST" action="http://example.com/download.php" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="file_name" value="<?php print $trying; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="song_name" value="<?php print $songname; ?>" />
    <input type="Submit"  class="btn btn-success" value="Download Song" /> 
</form>
```

Then within the download.php file I have the following.

```
$file = 'tmp/' . $_POST['file_name'] . '.mp3';

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header("Content-Type: audio/mp3");
readfile($file);
```

How ever when a user downloads a file it brings up something that looks like this `tmp-song-artist-song-name.mp3` any help is very appreciated!

Edit:

[Preview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBRTA.png)

This is what happens when I change the `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);` line to `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$songtitle);`

```
$songtitle = $_POST['song_name'];
```

It seems to fix the title issue but creates an entirely new issue which is not what we want.

Comment: `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);` - change it here

Comment: @rjdown change it to `$_POST['song_name']` ? When I do that it just downloads a static HTML file which is the reason why I am using the `$file ` string.

Comment: Sure, if that's what you want it to be

Comment: Looks like you just want `$_POST['file_name'] . '.mp3'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong Content-Disposition header. In your first post you have used full file name alongwith tmp/ and after editing you missded .mp3 at end. I have corrected your download file code below:

```
$file = 'tmp/' . $_POST['file_name'] . '.mp3';

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$_POST['file_name'] . '.mp3');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header("Content-Type: audio/mp3");
readfile($file);
```

Comment: Thanks! I had already solved but because he commented the fix I am going to hit this as the resolved answer!

Answer (score -1):

Remove 'tmp/' section from file name.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . str_replace('tmp/', '', $file));
```